shifted axes in Show
I want to plot two functions in one graphic. I wanted to do so by using Show.
Show[Plot[x,{x,0,4}],Plot[x^2,{x,0,4}]]

However I want the plots to be sfifted. I want the origin of the second plot to be at position (1,1) of the first plot. Of course I can do
Show[Plot[x,{x,0,4}],Plot[1+(x-1)^2,{x,0,4}]]

but how can I shift the axes as well. I want a plot with two coordinate systems. Is this possible?
Thanks for help, Zara

Do you want this?
Show[
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 4}],
 Plot[1 + (x - 1)^2, {x, 0, 4}],
 AxesOrigin -> {1, 1},
 Frame -> True]


You can also create your own axes:
Show[
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 4}],
 Plot[1 + (x - 1)^2, {x, 0, 4}],
 Graphics[AxisObject[{"Horizontal", 1, {0, 4}}, AxisStyle -> Red]],
 Graphics[AxisObject[{"Vertical", 1, {0, 4}}, AxisStyle -> Red]],
 Graphics[AxisObject[{"Horizontal", 0, {0, 4}}]],
 Graphics[AxisObject[{"Vertical", 0, {0, 4}}]]]



Thanks a lot, this is what I was looking for. I will create the axis by myself

You can use GeomericTransformation[]. For example,
g1 = Plot[x, {x, 0, 4}]


g2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 4}]


g2s = g2 /. (Graphics[p_, opt___] :> 
     Graphics[GeometricTransformation[p, TranslationTransform[{1, 1}]], opt]);

Show[pl1, pl2s]


